# How to add a warning as an error in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

I have a pyspark job which throws a warning of **Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldException**.
The spark job runs and completes after the warning.

How can I set this warning as an Error in log4j file so that if this warning comes it will be treated as an Error and the job will fail

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the log4j configuration file in your Spark application. The file is usually named log4j.properties or log4j.xml.
2. Open the log4j configuration file in a text editor.
3. Find the section that defines the log levels and log appenders.
4. Add or modify the log level configuration to treat the warning level as an error. For log4j.properties, add the following line:

   `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN, error_console` or xml, depending on your config
   `<root> <level value="INFO"/> <appender-ref ref="console"/> </root> <logger name="org.apache.spark" additivity="false"> <level value="WARN"/> <appender-ref ref="error_console"/> </logger>`

This configuration specifies that the logger for the package org.apache.spark should have a log level of WARN and an appender named error_console.

5. Configure the error_console appender to redirect log messages to a file or another output. For example, you can add the following lines for log4j.properties:

   `log4j.appender.error_console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender log4j.appender.error_console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.error_console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n`

You can modify the appender configuration to redirect the log messages to a file or a specific output of your choice.

After making these changes, the log4j configuration will treat warnings from the org.apache.spark package as errors. If the warning you mentioned is logged by Spark with the appropriate log level, it will trigger the error level configured, and the Spark job will fail as a result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: HI @Kalik Thanks for the answer.However I do not need all the warning as error.Only that certain type of warning should be considered as error.Can you please help with that?